# Is it possible for a thermoelectric generator to not have a heat source or heat sink?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

Specifically, the type of thermoelectric generator I am suggesting makes use of the ExB drift effect.

When electric and magnetic fields are perpendicular to one another, with infinite mobility of the medium, the particles in the electric field drift along cycloids that are perpendicular to the electric and magnetic fields. Unlike Seebeck and Nersnt effects, particles drift because of a field configuration, not because of drag by heat flow.

With infinite mobility of the medium, a return path has the same properties as a forward path and no energy can be extracted because the fields are conservative. However, with finite mobility, the drift becomes a function of dissipative properties such as mobility and concentration. High mobility and low concentration enable the drift while low mobility and high concentration disable the drift without altering the material's conductivity. This seems to suggest that a system with the drift enabled in a forward path and disabled in a return path can overcome the limitation of the conservative fields, thereby converting heat in the semiconductor to electrical energy without the presence of a heat source or heat sink.

Is there something I am missing, or does this appear to be accurate?

Comment: Dissipative properties = energy loss

Comment: Unfortunately I do not really understand well the setup. If you could make a sketch and/or clarify the setup, I would think about your question.

Answer (score 1):

No. From the thermodynamics point of view, [performing useful works requires heat transfer from a warmer body to a colder one, and there is no way of converting all the heat into useful work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics). This is a very general principle, although identifying the source and the sink, as well as their correct temperatures may be tricky. (Unfortunately thermo textbooks create false impression that their content applies only to the engines based on gas expansion, such as steam and internal combustion engines.)